# Replacing column values based on related column in R

Tags: r, replace, imputation

I'm currently working on a dataset which has an address and a zip code column. I'm trying to deal with the invalid/missing data in zip code by finding a different record with same address, and then filling the corresponding zip code to the invalid zip code. What would be the best approach to go about doing this?

Comment: `merge` by address could be useful

Comment: @R.Schifini wouldn't merge combine separate records?

Comment: Read [MCVE]. Show a similar situation to the one you are facing. We don’t really have the basis for building an answer yet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.** Using the non-missing addresses and zip codes construct a dictionary
data frame of sorts. For example, in a data frame "df" with an "address"
column and a "zip_code" column, you could get this via:

```
library(dplyr)
zip_dictionary <- na.omit(select(df, address, zip_code))
zip_dictionary <- distinct(zip_dictionary)
```

This assumes there is only one unique value of "zip_code" for each "address"
in your data. If not, you need to figure out which value to use and filter or
recode it accordingly.

**Step 2.** Install the {elucidate} package from GitHub and use the translate()
function to fill in the missing zip codes using the extracted dictionary from
step 1:

```
remotes::install_github("bcgov/elucidate")
library(elucidate)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(zip_code = if_else(is.na(zip_code),
                            translate(address,
                                      old = zip_dictionary$address,
                                      new = zip_dictionary$zip_code)
                            )
         )
```

disclaimer: I am the author of the {elucidate} package